# Hiding the toolbar from specific activity

Tags: android, xml, toolbar

For some reason the my MainActivity toolbar appeared again (after I removed all the toolbars from my app), with grey color (the rest of the app is blue). I want to remove it in the xml, and the layout theme is exactly the same as the rest of the app. Thats why I'm not sure what's wrong and couldn't find any solutions online.

styles:

```
    <style id="checkBoxStyle" name="checkBoxStyle" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#dc302e2e</item>
    <item name="android:editTextColor">#000000</item>
</style>
```

MainActivity layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/weakbeach"
    android:theme="@style/checkBoxStyle"
    tools:context="com.example.itay.newfrindlyalarm.MainActivity"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonSetting"
        android:layout_width="192dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#1a6ca3"
        android:text="Settings"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_add_alarm"
        android:layout_width="270dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/ligthSec"
        android:text="Add new Alarm:"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/buttonSetting"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/buttonSetting"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/alarmMessage" />

    <TimePicker
        android:id="@+id/alarmTimePicker"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="144dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:timePickerMode="spinner"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.00999999"></TimePicker>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/checkBoxDay4"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/alarmclock" />


    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBoxDay2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:button="@null"
        android:drawableRight="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
        android:text="M"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/checkBoxDay3"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/checkBoxDay4" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBoxDay7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:button="@null"
        android:drawableRight="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
        android:text="S"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/checkBoxDay6"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/checkBoxDay6"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBoxDay1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:button="@null"
        android:drawableRight="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
        android:text="S"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/checkBoxDay2"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/checkBoxDay2" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBoxDay6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:button="@null"
        android:drawableRight="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
        android:text="F"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/checkBoxDay5"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/checkBoxDay4"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBoxDay5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:button="@null"
        android:drawableRight="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
        android:text="T"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/checkBoxDay4"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/checkBoxDay4"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/checkBoxDay6" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBoxDay4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:button="@null"
        android:checked="false"
        android:drawableRight="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
        android:text="W"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.56"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/alarmTimePicker" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBoxDay3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:button="@null"
        android:drawableRight="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
        android:text="T"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/checkBoxDay4"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/checkBoxDay2"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/checkBoxDay4" />


    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/repeateButton"
        android:layout_width="88dp"
        android:layout_height="83dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/checkBoxDay1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/alarmTimePicker"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:drawable="@drawable/chenge_image_repeat"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.122" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/chenge_image_repeat"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/repeateButton"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/repeateButton" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/alarmMessage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:maxLength="32"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text=""
        android:hint="Enter Your Alarm message here"
        android:textColorHint="#767373"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/checkBoxDay4" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/alarm_list"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/buttonSetting"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button_add_alarm"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">


    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/ringtonesSpinner"
        android:layout_width="69dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="194dp" /><![CDATA[

        ;
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="32dp" />



]]>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

another activity layout (one thats the toolbar is removed, and the color is blue):

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="@drawable/cute_dog_n_pinguin"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:theme="@style/checkBoxStyle"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.itay.newfrindlyalarm.AlarmSettings">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_snozee_settings"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Snooze Settings:"
        android:textColor="@color/greySettings"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.15"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" />

    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/switch_snooze"
        android:checked="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="snooze on: "
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView_snozee_settings"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_snooze_time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Snooze time:"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/switch_snooze"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox_5"
        android:checked="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="5"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/checkBox_3"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/checkBox_3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/checkBox_3" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox_7"
        android:checked="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="7"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/checkBox_5"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/checkBox_5"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/checkBox_5" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox20"
        android:checked="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="20"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/checkBox_7"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/checkBox15"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/checkBox15" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox15"
        android:checked="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="15"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/checkBox_5"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/checkBox10"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/checkBox10" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox10"
        android:checked="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="10"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/checkBox_3"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox_3"
        android:checked="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="3"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView_snooze_time"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/checkBox10" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonRingtone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Set Ringtone"
        android:textColor="#d4d4d4"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/checkBox15"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.00999999" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I'm sure that the solution is simple, I just wasted 3 hours on trying to figure it out. Thanks a lot!

edit:
I added some pictures:
[MainActivity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ow6MI.png)

[How the Toolbar should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRIKr.png)

Comment: Could you post the whole layout of MainActivity? Or is that all?

Comment: I though the rest of it is irrelevant, my bad. I will post it all, its a little long

Comment: maybe you should extend Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar in your styles?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I'm not sure but you can check these things: 1. Make sure you're not creating a toolbar in the activity 2. Try adding this in your style <item name="windowActionBar">false</item> 3. Extend Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your help, but the problem was in the Manifest.
I needed to select the right theme for the activity in the Manifest, and not in the xml file
(The relevant Manifest part):

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
try this one

<style name="AppTheme.FullScreen">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```